# An error occurred while updating the entries. For more information, see inner exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework, razor

I am using Entity Framework to populate a grid control. It sometimes when I make updates I get the following error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. For more information, see inner exception.

This my action Edit :

```
public ActionResult Edit(CollaborateurSet collaborateur)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Entry(collaborateur).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        DilpomeDropDownList(collaborateur.Diplome_idDiplome);
        return View(collaborateur);
    }
}
```

And this is the view edit :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idCollaborateur)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom)
    </div>
```

Please tell me how can I resolve this error

Comment: Follow the detailed instruction in the error message you just pasted.

Comment: And **what IS the inner exception?** What does it tell you?

Comment: is the only errour, and there no other specification ; and whenn i put bind[exclude(collaborateur.id] i have this erroe: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Comment: and this is the exception waht i have : " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_CollaborateurCollaborateur". The conflict occurred in database "CollaborateurDBManagerRH", table "dbo.CollaborateurSet", column 'idCollaborateur'.
The statement has been terminated."